# Click on push notification opens new tab

Tags: web, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

I am using 3rd party service for sending a push notification to the end user but when I click on push notification, It opens a new tab and which is fine when the user is not surfing on my website but when it surfing it's iterating. Any Solution to control `onclick` event of push notification?

Any helpful answer will be appreciated.

Comment: How is the notification show? Service worker? chrome.notifications?

Comment: I am using http://pushcrew.com/ for notification service

Comment: any solution ? am also facing same issue.